# Preview Composable with a specific ApiLevel

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

In our theme, we use our color scheme or we built it with dynamicLight/DarkColorScheme.

```
fun AppTheme(...) {
    val colorScheme = when {
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S && isSystemInDarkTheme -> dynamicDarkColorScheme(LocalContext.current)
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> dynamicLightColorScheme(LocalContext.current)
        isSystemInDarkTheme -> darkColorScheme
        else -> lightColorScheme
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colorScheme,
        content = content,
    )
}
```

But all the previews use the dynamic scheme color, even if I specify an apiLevel in the Preview annotation.

```
@Preview(apiLevel = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Composable
private fun HomeScreenPreview() {
    AppTheme {
        HomeScreen()
    }
}
```

Isn't the purpose of the parameter? Am I missing something?

Comment: looks like `apiLevel` is broken, I've [reported](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/255902045) it. Next time you can report it too, proving a minimal reproduciable example, so it can be fixed faster